# Print previous 20 lines of text from a certain point of a text file

Tags: bash, shell-script

**Currently:**

I'm new to scripting, teaching myself as i go along and this is my first script I'm developing. What my script is trying to do is look at specified file, scan the file to find the word "Error". Currently it then prints the rest of the file from the point "ERROR" to an output file.

**Problem:**

After finding the word "ERROR" in a file, how can I Print the previous 20 lines of text from the word "ERROR" to an output file and append the rest of the file from the point "ERROR" to the same output file?

**Possible solution?**

Would I use some sort of loop here to do this?  I have the sudo code=in my head to how to do this might work but not sure how to actually implement this. Can anyone advise or tell me if there is a better way to do this?

**Script:**

```
my $file_handle = IO::File->new ('output','a') or die;

print $file_handle "*****************************\n";

while(<>) {

        print $file_handle $_ if(/.*ERROR/ .. /^XXX/);

        }
```

Comment: You have this tagged as bash, but your code is perl.  Are you wanting a perl solution or a bash solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `grep`'s `-B` (`--before-context`) option:

```
grep -B 20 error filename
```

Comment: Yep!  `-B` for before, `-A` for after, `-C` for both before and after ("context").

Comment: Now, the next requirement, how to append the rest of the file?

Comment: I would suggest: `grep -B 20 ERROR file && awk '/ERROR/ {p=1; next} p' file`

Answer (score 0):

awk: I'm just keeping 5 lines for this demo, adjust the "keep" value to 20

```
{ seq 10; echo ERROR; seq 6; } |
awk -v keep=5 '
  /ERROR/ {
    for (i=keep; i>=1; i--) print lines[i]  # the stored lines
    print                                   # the current line
    while (getline > 0) print               # all the remaining lines
  }
  {
    # remember the previous "keep" lines.
    for (i=keep; i>1; i--)
      lines[i] = lines[i-1]
    lines[1] = $0
  }
'
```

```
6
7
8
9
10
ERROR
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Another approach: takes 2 reads through the file, but it's clearer, I think.

```
keep=20
lineno=$(sed -n '/ERROR/{=;q;}' file)
[[ -n $lineno ]] && sed -n "$((lineno-keep)),\$p" file
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this in bash, I'd do it something like this:

```
line=$(grep -m1 -n ERROR the_file | cut -f1 -d:)
if ((line <= 20)); then
  cat the_file;
else
  tail -n+$((line-20)) the_file
fi
```

which uses `grep` with the "show line numbers"· option to get the line number of the match, and then `tail -n` to print the starting with the 20th previous line, being careful to avoid a negative starting line number.

In any other language, the solution would be to keep a rolling (maybe circular) buffer of the last 20 lines read. For example, in awk, with a circular buffer:

```
awk -v P=20 'found  { print; next }
             /ERROR/{ for (i=NR+1;i<=NR+P;++i) 
                        if (i%P in saved)
                          print saved[i%P]
                      found = 1
                    }
                    { saved[NR%P] = $0 }'
```